# Автоматическое создание картинки для анонса товара в каталоге из дополнительных изображений 1C Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией
В интернет магазине у всех товаров в каталоге загружены изображения через множественной свойство инфоблока MORE_PHOTO. Изображения анонса и детального описания отсутствуют.

Возможно ли создать скрипт для автоматического создания и ресайза изображения анонса товаров из первого дополнительного изображения MORE_PHOTO. Находил что-то подобное про это , но скрипт не сработал.

```html
Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('iblock');
$rsItems = \CIBlockElement::GetList(
    ['ID' => 'ASC'],
    [
        'IBLOCK_ID' => 15 // Замените  на ИД вашего инфоблока
    ],
    false,
    false,
    ['ID','DETAIL_PICTURE','PREVIEW_PICTURE','MORE_PHOTO']
);
while ($arItem = $rsItems->Fetch()) {
    if (intval($arItem['DETAIL_PICTURE']) == 0
        && is_array($arItem['MORE_PHOTO'])
        && count($arItem['MORE_PHOTO']) > 0) {
            $arFields =array();
            $arFields["PREVIEW_PICTURE"] = CFile::GetFileArray($arItem['MORE_PHOTO'][0]);
            $arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"] = CFile::GetFileArray($arItem['MORE_PHOTO'][0]);
            if ($arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"] !== false) {
                $el = new CIblockElement();
                $el->Update($arItem['ID'],$arFields);
            }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Мой вариант решения вопроса: https://scoder.ru/dev/course13/lesson69/?LESSON_PATH=33.65.69
Как один из возможных. Почти все учтено.

Answer (score 0):

Если это скрипт из типового решения, то попробуйте добавить "echo" для отладки цикла, - проверьте на каком этапе проблема, какая переменная в условии что показывает.

Если скрипт не из битрикса - возможно имеет смысл воспользоваться одной из библиотек для работы с изображениями на php.